Option to hide some folders or files in git (source control) view in VSCODE when working on a monorepo
I have a monorepo for a project with multiple services and apps and libraries. Instead of using sparse checkouts in different folders, I have checked out the full repository in one folder on my local dev machine.
Now I have opened up to 5 VSCODE Windows - each with a different part or service of my monorepo.
To work on it that is fine and OK.
BUT
When looking on the Source Control Panel to commit changes, I always see ALL FILES CHANGES in any of this 5 VSCODE Windows. It would great if I could set some setting in the Workspace settings, to hide the other files just from source control.
Let's say there are

apps/

one
two
three



and I want only to see apps/one/* in the source control panel from VSCODE window 1 - and - apps/two/* in the source control panel from VSCODE window 2 - and - apps/three/* in the source control panel from VSCODE window 3.
Currently I see always apps/* in the source control panel from all 3 open VSCODE windows.
Any idea or suggestions are welcome

all files changed? Sounds like an EOL adjustment. Show us the output of git config -l; git config --global -l.

Sorry - all files changed inside my project folder for
apps/*
which is expected.
